# Importing Git Project into eclipse error

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven

I imported a maven project from GITHUB and I find errors in the code. i.e. it is not able to update dependencies. Like @Entity. I find that all the jars get added through pom but I still find that error. I am attaching a screen shot for the same.

I am using mac. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: You may want to clone the project from the command line and ensure that it builds correctly from the command line first (which brings all needed dependencies into your local repository).  Then you can import an existing maven project into Eclipse.

Comment: How do i do that?I don't understand that

Comment: Clone the github repository from a command line - `git clone ....` - and then build it with maven from the command line.

Comment: I am really sorry but you need to give me some references to see how it is actually done. I have no idea about it and I am missing a lot because of that. What I know is that there is download open for all the open projects and then I import them. Can you list out in detail or give me some references.

Comment: If this is a maven project, you _should_ be able to (after ensuring git is installed e.g. from https://windows.github.com/ and maven from https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) to first _clone_ the repository so you have the files on your local disk and then use maven to build the project.  If you are unfamiliar with this, I strongly recommend that you spend some time learning.  Github has a lot of help available on https://help.github.com/, and Maven has help starting at https://maven.apache.org/install.html.